# Calling Smarties display() method multiple times vs using includes

Tags: smarty

Which method of pulling together the templated parts of my site is best practice? I prefer the first solution, but I'm not sure using multiple calls to display() is good practice. I'm looking for ease of maintenance and speed.

```
<?php
$smarty->display('header.tpl');
$smarty->display('menu.tpl');
$smarty->display('article1.tpl');
$smarty->display('footer.tpl');
?>
```

or displaying a single smarty template and then within the template having

```
{include file="header.tpl"}
<body id={$pageid}>
{include file="menu.tpl"}
{include file="header_inner.tpl"}

Content of page

{include file="footer.tpl"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Smarty3 (which you should) have a look at [Inheritance](http://www.smarty.net/inheritance) and [Template Inheritance](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.template.inheritance.tpl). It allows you to define templates much like you'd build your classes - OOP style.

If you can't (or don't want to) roll with TI, I'd suggest the `{include}` approach. Reasons:

1. Reducing API between PHP and templates
2. allows [output caching](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.tpl) in a simpler fashion
3. allows [$cache_modified_check](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.cache.modified.check.tpl) for basic `HTTP 304 Not Modified` handling right out of the box
4. can be optimized (by Smarty3) through [{include … inline}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl) to reduce filesystem I/O
5. can be generally optimized (by Smarty3) through [$merge_compiled_includes](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.merge.compiled.includes.tpl) (still reducing filesystem I/O)

There is (only) one advantage of multiple display() calls. You can push data to the browser in chunks. So you could flush the  to the browser before your  is rendered. This allows the browser to fetch (blocking) resources like scripts and css before it even received the whole document. ("Pipelining the loading Of documents")

As for maintainability, I'm using TI and {include} approaches. Never multiple display() calls. I'd have to touch too many scripts If something changed.