# Template of Templates Using Smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

I recently started using [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), which can greatly reduce the boilerplate code in a web page.

How I can extend the idea of reducing boilerplate code further by using Smarty to make a template of the `.php` and associated `.tpl` files? Or, is there a simpler, if less "meta", approach?

For example, consider a web site where all pages have the same menu and sidebar. One can use Smarty to generate the HTML code for each of the menu items for a given page. Is there a way to generate the `.tpl` files as well because they share so much in common? (Perhaps the fact that so much of my design can be automated on two levels suggests a poor design?)

Is this as simple as using one PHP file to generate another?

To provide a more concrete example, I generated the index page of [this web site](http://tox.sinaiem.org/) using Smarty. As you can see, [some](http://tox.sinaiem.org/about.html) of the [other](http://tox.sinaiem.org/projects.html) [pages](http://tox.sinaiem.org/team.html) are close enough that I think one could generate the HTML more parsimoniously. I think a mechanism that generates Smarty templates for each page is a reasonably approach, although I am not exactly sure how to proceed.

**Related SO Question**

This question, [Calling Smarties display() method multiple times vs using includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019093/calling-smarties-display-method-multiple-times-vs-using-includes), refers to Template inheritance, which may be the OOP analogue of what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: What information are you looking for that isn't answered by the other question? The answer says that {include} is the good way to re-use templates in other templates, which does what you want surely.

Comment: The other post does completely answer it. I flagged this as a duplicate. I didn't immediately delete it in case the moderators felt that it could be a useful signpost to that question because of different wording.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Smarties display() method multiple times vs using includes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019093/calling-smarties-display-method-multiple-times-vs-using-includes)

Comment: @Jack: That's why I linked to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do, which might not be the best method but might help you out, is to have a global template, which includes templates for `header`, `menu`, `footer`, etc... and include a data driven `content` template.

```
{* Smarty Template *}
{* Core Template *}
{* Multi-lang - Loads all inner components of the page *}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        {include file=$lang|cat:"/head.tpl"}
    </head>
    <body>
        {include file=$lang|cat:"/menu.tpl"}
        {include file=$lang|cat:"/body.tpl"}
        {include file=$lang|cat:"/footer.tpl"}
    </body>
</html>
```

Where I will have a simple `body.tpl` that can do as little as:

```
{* Smarty Template *}
{* Base Template for BODY *}
<div>
    {include file=$lang|cat:"/"|cat:$view|cat:".tpl"}
</div>
```

Where `$view` represents the `content` I want to have displayed (another template). As you can see, my setup is made to be multilanguage, you can drop the `$lang|cat:` part if you don't want to handle more than one language.

If you wanted to have some pages override the `head` or `menu`, it would be pretty easy to do something like:

```
{if isset($headerOverride) }
    {include file=$headerOverride}
{else}
    {include file=$lang|cat:"/head.tpl"}
{/if}
```

By breaking your templates in smaller chunks that are overridables I think you can keep a pretty solid structure for your templates and still allow the exceptions to load custom code.